# How to compute SHA256 hash for bitcoin header

Tags: ruby, bitcoin, sha256

I am trying to understand the proof of work algorithm. I computed a block header (which includes the nonce):

```
"02000000aaf8ab82362344f49083ee4edef795362cf135293564c4070000000000000000c009bb6222e9bc4cdb8f26b2e8a2f8d163509691a4038fa692abf9a474c9b21476800755c02e17181fe6c1c3"
```

I have to apply SHA256 to this twice. The correct answer is supposed to be:

```
"00000000000000001354e21fea9c1ec9ac337c8a6c0bda736ec1096663383429"
```

I tried `pack`, `unpack`, `hex`, etc., but I can't get this output. What is the correct Ruby code to convert the input to the output using SHA256?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
header_hex = "02000000aaf8ab82362344f49083ee4edef795362cf135293564c4070000000000000000c009bb6222e9bc4cdb8f26b2e8a2f8d163509691a4038fa692abf9a474c9b21476800755c02e17181fe6c1c3"

# Decode header hex into binary string
header = [header_hex].pack("H*")

# Apply SHA256 twice
require "digest"
d1 = Digest::SHA256.digest(header)
d2 = Digest::SHA256.digest(d1)

# Convert to hex
result = d2.unpack("H*").join
# => "293438636609c16e73da0b6c8a7c33acc91e9cea1fe254130000000000000000"
```

Oops, for some reason the result is somewhat "backwards". Perhaps it is a byte-ordering issue? Let's try that again with the binary data reversed:

```
result = d2.reverse.unpack("H*").join
# => "00000000000000001354e21fea9c1ec9ac337c8a6c0bda736ec1096663383429"
```

Bingo!

*Edit: Just to clarify, this was a trial-and-error solution. I don't have any special insight into the proof of work algorithm!*

Comment: thank you!  I have 90% of the proof of work in ruby figured out over on bitcoin stack exchange, this makes it complete.  (The 90% is because the solution is in python).  Thanks again.

Comment: my mistake, pls ignore.

Comment: nice explanation now lets make it a 1 liner :) `2.times.inject([header_hex].pack("H*")){|header| Digest::SHA256.digest(header)}.reverse.unpack("H*").join`